# Why does curl give me html instead of file?

Tags: linux, curl

I'm trying (learning) to use `curl` to download the file `http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_maps.vim` . The commands I have tried are:

```
curl -o cscope_maps.vim cscope.sourceforce.net/cscope_maps.vim
curl -O cscope.sourceforce.net/cscope_maps.vim
curl -LO cscope.sourceforce.net/cscope_maps.vim
curl -L cscope.sourceforce.net/cscope_maps.vim > cscope_maps.vim
```

All of the above commands result in me getting a file with the following content:

```
<html><head><script type="text/javascript">location.replace("https://malware.opendns.com/?url=cscope.sourceforce.net%2Fcscope_maps.vim&server=lax20&prefs=&tagging=&nref");</script></head></html>
```

...instead of the actual file. What am I doing wrong, and what is the correct syntax to download a file with `curl`?

(If I enter the noted URL in a graphical browser, I see expected file contents, so I'm sure the URL is correct)

PS: I'd like to learn how to solve this with `curl` and not `wget`.

**What else I have tried**:

I read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458797/curl-command-doesnt-download-the-file-linux-mint which prompted me to try the `-L` options, but as noted above, this did not change the observed behavior.

Comment: Your first command (using `-o` for output) actually works. I tried it on my side. I think the problem might be on the DNS. If you look at your output, instead of getting the contents of `cscope_maps.vim`, you're getting warning from opendns that you are downloading malware. Check your antivirus or firewall, perhaps?

Comment: Your examples have "`sourceforce.net`" URLs, but what you want is at  http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_maps.vim, right? (“forge” instead of “force”) …

Comment: @sideshowbarker and Fox: good catch. I also didn't notice the typo on the URL. FYI, the output file that was given by the curl running on my machine is listing the domain for sale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your opening statement indicates you are trying to download from `sourceforge.net`

> " I'm trying (learning) to use `curl` to download the file `http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_maps.vim` ..."

However, your attempts are using sourcefor`c`e.net

This [curl man page](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/ssen/src/curl-7.11.1/docs/curl.html) describes what you are trying to do:

> curl [options] [URL...]

with the `-o` option being what you're looking for:

> -o/--output
>
> Write output to  instead of stdout. If you are using {} or [] to fetch multiple documents, you can use '#' followed by a number in the  specifier. That variable will be replaced with the current string for the URL being fetched. Like in:
>
> curl http://{one,two}.site.com -o "file_#1.txt"
>
> or use several variables like:
>
> curl http://{site,host}.host[1-5].com -o "#1_#2"
>
> You may use this option as many times as you have number of URLs.

Your first attempt should work once you correctly spell `sourceforge`

```
curl -o cscope_maps.vim cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_maps.vim
```

This worked for me.

Comment: I should crawl and hide under a rock for the rest of my life out of abject embarrassment. I can't believe I posted a question in public over a typo. Thank you: you were correct, my attempts worked once I spelled the URL correctly.